# Rafrex SPA 404 Helper - Github Pages - 404 Page Grabbing All Other Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application, github-pages

I'm using github pages to deploy my personal website. My personal website and many of the other pages being hosted through github use React and React router.

As a result, I've employed [Rafrex' SPA](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages) in order to prevent a 404 page getting served on refresh. Unfortunately, other projects hosted on github pages get "overwritten" by rafrex since they're not technically an existing route on my website. E.G refreshing on `personalwebsite.com/validpage` redirects appropriately to that existing page, but `personalwebsite.com/othergithubproject` gets snatched by rafrex and just displays whatever would normally get displayed on "/". This can be fixed by clearing out the cache on the page and then refreshing but obviously is not a good solution for visitors.

Have I missed something obvious when using Rafrex-SPA? Is this just a flaw in Rafrex-SPA? Is there a good workaround? Thank you!

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as you are experiencing. I found that the service worker that is part of create react app to be causing the issue. When I disabled it, everything worked correctly. Are you using a service worker?

Comment: Yes, definitely using the default CRA service worker. I ended up writing a workaround that did work for me [here](https://medium.com/@thomaslaird/multiple-react-router-app-deployments-on-github-pages-rafrex-spa-f8f9de04dacf). 

Disabling the service worker makes some sense to me as a fix but I'd be curious to know why that would be causing the issue. Something to do with caching maybe?